# PHP: str_replace() - ignore white space

Tags: php, whitespace, str-replace

I have a string that is something like `,  ] }`

I'd like to replace it with `] }`

The problem is I don't know whether there will be white space between the `,` and the `]`. There may be white space or there may be no white space. There may be tabs or there may be line breaks.

How can I replace `,<any white space here>] }` to just `] }` please?

Comment: use regex `preg_replace('@\,[\h\s]+@', '', $string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `str_replace` you can simply use `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace('/,\s*\]\s*}/',"] }",$string);
```

- `\s*` `\s` checks for any space character that includes `new line,tabs,space` and `*` for zero or more occurence of space
- `\]\s*}` this'll check for the `]` `brace` `\s*` as specified above and `}` curly brace literally

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$str = preg_replace('/,\s*(?=]\s*})/', "", $str);
```

- `\s*` means any amount of any whitespace (`\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]`)
- `(?=]\s*})` the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used to check if `,\s*` is followed by `]\s*}`

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/471079)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this was without testing. This is an alternative of `preg_replace`. This will trim specified in the second parameter, `\t`, `\n`, , `,`. So after trimming, you will be left with `]}`

```
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed)

echo ltrim($string, ", \t\n");
```

if you are uncertain that there might be a carriage return, or a vertical tab in there, you can

```
echo ltrim(ltrim($str1, ","));
```

This will first trim down the comma then trim these characters , , `\t`, `\r`, `\0`, `\x0B`

Here's a [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w954Kn)

Comment: Can you add details as to why this works, what this actually does? cheers

Comment: @martin updated answer in a more appropriate overview