# how to ignore white spaces in php substr

Tags: php, substr

I want to display the first 100 characters of a user's bio and then put an option of Read More, that will open a new page with complete details. Following is my code:

```
<p>
<?php echo substr($search->bio, 0, 100); ?>..... <a href='<?=base_url();?>user/profile/<?php echo $search->user_id; ?>'>Read more</a>
</p>
```

Now the problem with the code is that it also counts the white space as character. Is there any way to ignore the spaces? Please Help.

Comment: Instead of counting characters, count words with regex.

Comment: I am new to php. Can u plz help me with code?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778142/php-str-replace-ignore-white-space